# MODBUS TCP Read response query - second opinion required

Tags: modbus, tcp-ip

I am having an interoperability problem between a Modbus/TCP driver from one company and a Modbus/TCP device from another.

The Modbus driver I am using seems to be able to correctly read all but four of the available registers within the device (which should bring back two results that are used in my application).  I have included a screenshot below, which shows the typical request (from the Modbus driver) and the response (from the Modbus device) using Wireshark.

Is there a problem with the response and does it explain why the Modbus driver may not be picking up values for the queried registers?

I have tried another application which polls these same registers and it was able to correctly receive the expected values, which only seems to add to my dilemma . . .

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why does the response contain HTML markup, is it supposed to? Also, I think Wireshark can decode Modbus-TCP, is it working? (Maybe you'll need to enable it with right-click, decode-as, or similar.)

Comment: interestingly, that seems to change between read requests - sometimes all 00's, other times it appears random.

Comment: Sounds like the other device is happily responding with random memory (a bug) instead of errors. Modbus has distinct function codes for single/multi register read, maybe this makes the difference between working/not working?

Comment: I'm trying not influence the outcome of the second opinion I'm seeking, but I thought the value "cb" in the response (line 0030) might be noteworthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it definitely looks strange to me.

I read it as

```
READ-HOLDING-REGISTERS(addr=0x082f, nwords=4) 
=> [0x0000, 0x736b, 0x0000, 0x0a7b]
```

**but with lots of trash in the return**.

```
#       / transaction id
#       |     / protocol
#       |     |     / nbytes
#       |     |     |     / unit
#       |     |     |     |  / opcode
#       |     |     |     |  |  / addr
#       |     |     |     |  |  |     / nword
#       |     |     |     |  |  |     |
        00 00 00 00 00 06 01 03 08 2f 00 04 <== from wireshark
```

and the result

```
#       / transaction id
#       |     / protocol
#       |     |     / nbytes
#       |     |     |     / unit
#       |     |     |     |  / opcode
#       |     |     |     |  |  / nbyte
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  / word 0
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  |     / word 1
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  |     |     / word 2
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  |     |     |     / word 3
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  |     |     |     |     / trash!
#       |     |     |     |  |  |  |     |     |     |     |     
        00 00 00 00 00 cb 01 03 08 00 00 73 6b 00 00 0a 7b 6f 6c 6c 69 00 00 0f e1 61  <== from Wireshark
                       ^ peculiar, expecting 0x0b          ^ peculiar
```

So I agree with you: the outer `nbytes` seems a crazy value of 0xcb, when we'd expect 8 + 3 = 0x0b.  And there is a lot of random buffer coming after, which we'd expect to change according to what the device has been doing -- it's definitely a memory leak bug.  But by [robustness principle](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc761#section-2.10) isn't actually a protocol error, and could be considered padding (I'll re-read the Modbus protocol for anything about padding later.)

**Are those four response words correct?  What are you expecting?**

For Modbus/TCP you should have a 7-byte "MBAP Header" followed by the 5-byte query or (nwords * 2 + 2) bytes of response (or 2-byte error).

From *MODBUS MESSAGING ON TCP/IP IMPLEMENTATION GUIDEV1.0b*:

[image]

From *MODBUS Application Protocol Specification V1.1b3*:
[image]

I've seen extraordinary bugs in Modbus implementations, my suggestion would be to try different value for nwords, different starting Modbus addresses and see if you still get your problem.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hi jonathanjo, thank you for your response. Yes, despite the trash, the values in words 0 - 3 appear correct.  I'll try to see if there is anything that can be done in terms of reading the registers, as suggested.  I did try reading just two words, but I still saw the same problem.  This particular block of 4 words are addressed much higher than any of the other Modbus registers I needed, so because of the big gap, I configured the driver to read these words separately.  Trying to read the lower values and these values didn't appear to work.

Comment: Is the client driver going wrong because of the extra 0xc0 bytes?  "Addressed much higher" ... how much higher?  I also see that your address is an odd number, have you tried organising it so it's an even numbered address.  Some PLC-type devices have shocking bugs with "nonaligned" reads and writes.

Comment: I used a program called "Modbus Server" to mimic the problematic registers and my application worked correctly.  Looking at the response from "Modbus Server" in Wireshark, the nbytes value was 0x0b and there was also no trash.

Comment: Just trying to clarify: the extra bytes are causing malfunction in the driver?

Comment: Currently, I can only clarify that with an nbytes value of 0x0b and no trash, the driver works, but I can't say for sure if the application would work if it received a response with the correct nbytes value and the trash.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still trying to underwhat what error symptom you're getting.  (No response? Error response?  Timeout?)  I note there is a suggestion in the Modbus/TCP doc that you could put multiple responses in the one PDU, and that it would be a bad idea (p10: "It is advised against sending multiple MODBUS requests or responses on the same TCP PDU").  If the receiver starts parsing the junk as the next response, it will go wrong.  To me I'd say there are two bugs: sender is sending garbage "padding". receiver isn't robust the dribble-on responses ("padding").

Comment: If you can't fix one end or work around it, you cuold consider putting a modbus-relay in between.  Horrible, but will work.  Depends what coding experience and platforms you have available, but in principle it's not so tricky.

Comment: At the moment, excluding the problematic registers, my highest register I currently read is 42002, but there are some at 42030 which I could try reading (just to alter the request and see if the trash disappears).. A timeout appears to be the error reported by the driver.  The Modbus relay sounds like a good backup plan, if all else fails.

Comment: The main problem (and the reason for the post) is that the device supplier refuses point blank to accept there is an issue (despite more than 10 new units and an older unit all displaying the same symptoms).  I have now written to the supplier of the Modbus driver, but I'm pretty sure they'll come back and say that the nbytes value is not one you'd expect for a hypothetical response of 8 + 3 bytes and that's before they mention the trash.  Does the robustness principle stand? There seems quite a bit of scope to consider the response questionable, do padded bytes need to be 00?  Thank you.

Comment: My opinion is that the driver has a bug because it shouldn't do anything at all with data after `response.byte_count` but within the `mbp.length`.  I accept that someone might implement "multiple response in single mbp", in which case you'd expect some kind of error report (because the trash isn't properly formulated modbus reponse); but the standard explicitly says you should only do one message per mbp.  The sending device clearly has a bug because it's sending garbage length with garbarge values.

Comment: My comment about robustness principle is that in my opinion driver should cope with this buggy reponse, because it's absolutely clear what it should do.  Most embedded and process control firmware engineers have no experience of security and are not committed to interoperability.  "Well it works with our devices" is usually sufficient in their organisations.  This is not satisfactory, in my opinion.

Comment: @dwp321 please join the chat I've made "modbus interop"

Comment: I tried a different Modbus driver, but the result from the device was still the same (a seemingly static nbytes value + trash).  I can definitely agree on your point that the driver should be more "liberal" with the data it receives, but ultimately, going back to the vendor and asking them to make changes to accept a wrong nbytes value + trash might be a bit of a stretch.  Today I received some good news!  The device manufacturer has been able to replicate my issue and does at least see the trash, so I'm hopefully they'll have a fix soon.  Thank you for your help on this :)

Comment: Glad that helps.  I have a certain amount of testbench software for generating bad modbus (for testing my modbus drivers), we could conceivably set up some tests for your driver.  And as suggested, you could put a "cleaning proxy" in the way if you need to force your equipment.